# TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'theme.label') Error

Tags: react-native, expo

I am having this issue with expo and npm. Anyone has any idea how to resolve this?[Error is here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHbd2.jpg)

Comment: Can't seem to get any clues or something; tried to look for the keywords but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there! This issue most often occurs when migrating from expo31 to expo32, when you update your react-navigation.

Try to migrate from expo31 to expo33. Skip expo32.

Comment: How do i migrate from expo31 to expo 33?

Comment: At the end of this article https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v33-0-0-is-now-available-52d1c99dfe4c   you can find the block "Upgrading Your App" and just follow the instructions, just try maybe it helps.

Comment: Yeah !! glad to hear ))